# Removing white Corrosion on my rice cooker heating element

Tags: cleaning

How do I remove it or is it safe to just leave it?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  It would help folks answer your question if you could share a photo.

Answer (score 1):

From your brief description, it appears that you have a deposit of [(lime)scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limescale) on your heating element.  Scale is mainly calcium carbonate and is commonly formed due to [hard water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_water).  It is often found in kettles, coffee makers, etc. which use hard water.

The usual way of dealing with it is to run the appliance with vinegar in place of or in addition to the water.

If what you have is actually [corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrosion) of the element, indicated by dissolution of the element, then I would be hesitant to use the rice maker.